# Error running powershell task in TFS Build vnext

Tags: asp.net-core, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

I have a very simple script which spits out environment variables like this:

```
Write-Host "SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECT: $ENV:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECT"
```

My build has one step, the PowerShell task. The task script filename is set to the path to the script in TFSVC e.g. $/Main/BuildProcessTemplates/AllProps.ps1.

When I queue a new build it fails reporting the following error: *"The term 'C:\Builds\agent_work\cb535ea3\Main' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again."*

Have I configured the task incorrectly?

-- UPDATE: Here's a copy of the powershell task
[image: View of PowerShell Task]

Comment: Looks like you need to put quotes around your command location.

Comment: Or call it using `"$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\Main\BuildProcessTemplates\AllProps.ps1"`

Comment: Solved, needed to include the powershell script under the Repository tab so that it is also checked out when building.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under the repository tab you need to include the script like below. If you have a directory of scripts you can select the folder instead.

[image]